# authorize with LinkedIn's API directly

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

Searching the LinkedIn API without authorizing a user

I want to use linkedin api to search companies in linkedin and get the linkedin page of those companies.

I'm trying to authorize with linkedin api directly - outside the context of any specific user.
Linkedin documentation mentioned that my application will not have the ability to use LinkedIn's client credentials flow. link to documentation: (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v2/oauth2-client-credentials-flow).
As noted, i tried to grant client credentials and its not possible - i got the following error:

```
{
    error: 'access_denied',
    error_description: 'This application is not allowed to create application tokens'
}
```

How can i enable this option?

Comment: Have you obtained your authentication keys from linkedin yet? Because the error indicates you are not authorized hence your access is denied. Do note that the image they show in the page you linked, is not your key rather it is an example key only. Make sure you complete the first configuration step whereby you get authorization from linkedin (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2#configure).

Comment: yes, i obtained the authentication keys from linkedin, and i complete the first step.
in the attached link linkedin writes that i should ask them for permission to get the access token out of the context of any user.

Comment: @DorDamry were you able to resolve this issue? I have the same issue